# "Error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired" when create product in WooCommerce via REST API

Tags: rest-api, ssl

Everything worked fine a week ago. Lets Encrypt certificate on the site is valid. I am currently getting the following error while creating a product:

```
{"code":"woocommerce_product_image_upload_error","message":"Error getting remote image https:\/\/mysite.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/10\/60c739fd1-1.jpg. Error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired","data":{"status":400}}
```

In this case, the picture is available by the URL.
Tried these solutions ([https://wp-kama.com/note/error-making-request-wordpress[enter](https://wp-kama.com/note/error-making-request-wordpress%5Benter) link description here][1](https://wp-kama.com/note/error-making-request-wordpress)) but doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

In the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf, you need to find the line:

```
mozilla / DST_Root_CA_X3.crt
```

and put the "!" symbol at the beginning of the dates:

```
! mozilla / DST_Root_CA_X3.crt
```

Next, you need to run the command:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a one liner, that can be added to a `Dockerfile` with `RUN` or just ran in the terminal

```
# Fix Outdate Let's Encrypt cert
curl --silent --insecure https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem >> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/isrgrootx1.pem && \
    sed -i 's=mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt=!mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt=g' /etc/ca-certificates.conf && \
    update-ca-certificate
```

It pulls down the latest cert insecurely so carries risk.

This didn't resolve the problem for me because PHP was using a different trust store from the systemwide one.

Our apache2 instance which is running PHP was in a Docker container. The trust store needed to be updated with a script just before the start of apache2, because it was created at runtime overwriting any changes made before execution.

Setting the path to `true` should use the system trust store rather than a custom bundle.

```
# Pull updated CA cert bundle
CERT_PATH=/var/www/html/wp-includes/certificates
mkdir -p $CERT_PATH && curl --silent https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem > $CERT_PATH/ca-bundle.crt
```